# Update previous views when editing current view

Tags: ios, view, controller, notifications, updates

In short, here is my problem:

1. I go from view controller A to VC B
2. Then from VC B to VC A.
3. Loop 1 and 2 for a number of times. All by pushing.
4. Now I edit VC A (e.g. Liking one of my post) and save. Then I go back by tapping on Back button. I want to see the changes in VC A (e.g. The number of likes increase 1 in my post)

That is the simple case when I only have 2 VCs. You can have many VCs in the loop, and you can may want to update other VCs not in the loop as well.

One example is in social network app like Instagram, where you can go to your profile, followers list, go to sb's profile, go to their follower list, go to your profile from there..so on and so on. Then at the end you make a like of one post, and you want to update view in Home tab, as well as all views  in middle of the loop, while you tapping on Back button.

I know we can implement in 2 ways:

1. In each VC, in viewwillappear we check for update and then update. The disadvantage is that it will not work in offline mode. And it is bulky to check everywhere.
2. Use notification. One view having changes will notify other views to update. But you have to define by yourself which views will accept which types of notification, and having multiple notification triggered in your app is quite messy and hard to manage.

Are there any other ways? How are you doing in your app?

My question is more of asking about architect, not for coding sample, so please answer by giving a solution, an architecture and some short analysis of the result of it.

This question is for both ios and android.

Comment: You can use the method 1 to achieve your target. You should maintain the separate table for update and when you coming back it to 1st VC check the update table contents with main table and then load the view

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is

Save the number of likes and the post id in NSUserDefaults and check in each view controller while your post id is same as the value in NSUserDefaults the increment it by your count of like for the post in NSUserDefaults . But at some point of time you have to sync it with webservice .

Comment: Right idea, but use a proper data model, don't a use NSUserDefaults

Comment: Yes, that is my solution 1. I may use coredata or sqlite to store data about updates. Never use NSUserdefault to store such data.

Comment: I still want information of people who implemented solution 2 and see how is the result. Have you ever implemented solution 2 @Paulw11?

Comment: I frequently use NSNotification in my apps - either as a result of some state change in the data model or in response to a 'silent' push notification